# Create shortcut icon to deploy project VS

Tags: c#, winforms, setup-deployment

I  want to create a setup for project. So, I've read this article [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/creating-an-msi-package-for-C-Sharp-windows-application-using-a-v/).

Now , I want to add a shortcut icon to Desktop, so , when i add the icon like in the following steps it doesn't appear in the dialog box **Current icon** and then i can't clik to the button OK

[image]

Please help.Thanks

Comment: add an icon file into your application folder first

Comment: I meant application folder of your setup project. Where you have created the Input folder.

Comment: Yes , I understood , i've added first then when i click to this icon this dialog box (Icon) appear and in there , we don't have any icon :/

Comment: How did you add the icon file ? Have you tried browsing and selecting your icon file ?

Comment: In the properties > icon> browse > Application Folder > Add File and then I clik to the icon added finally, we show  the dialog box above